# Change the IP Address of the Portal Database

Tags: websphere, portal-server

We are moving the Portal server (IBM Portal server V8.0) from Physical to Azure. Currently the Portal server is running on XX.XX.XX.01 and Portal DB is running on XX.XX.XX.02.
We are moving the same Image of portal server and DB server into Azure.
When the portal server was installed on the Physical server, the Portal DB IP Address was hard coded instead of the IP Hostname.

This is causing a big issue for us, unable to create the same IP Address on the Azure for DB and Portal server. Need to change the DB IP Address in the Portal server on Azure.
I have tried all my possibilities and could not find the solution.
Please assist . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change the IP Address of the Portal DB in Deployment Manager and the cluster instances by using the below steps.

```
1.I have installed grepWin software.
2.I have searched the Old IP Address(XX.XX.XX.01) in *.xml (mostly resources.xml) and *.properties.
3.Then replaced the New IP Address(xx.xx.xx.02) in all the files
5.Then started the Deployment Manager and the Cluster instances .
6.Able to start the Portal server using the  XX.XX.XX.02 Database.
```